# Position img on left and h1 on right

Tags: html, css

I'm learning CSS and HTML and I'm trying to make a simple looking portfolio page. This is how I want it to looks like:

[image]

HTML code for image on the left and text on the right:

```
<h1 id="appTitle">Beautiful Voice Recorder<br /><p id="appDescription">The simplest and best looking voice<br /> recorder you'll find on Google Play.</p></h1>
<img src="imgs/voice_recorder.png" alt="slider" id="appImg" />
```

CSS styling:

```
#appImg{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
#appTitle{
    font-size: 60px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

It's all messed up and I just can't manage to make it work since I'm a beginner. Could you please let me know how do I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `img` to the top of your floating items.

Like this:

```
<img src="imgs/voice_recorder.png" alt="slider" id="appImg" />
<h1 id="appTitle">Beautiful Voice Recorder<br /><p id="appDescription">The simplest and best looking voice<br /> recorder you'll find on Google Play.</p></h1>
```

Floats break content out of the normal layout and collapses with what is bellow.

Comment: I did, now it just moves the image to the center of the website and the text disappears.

Comment: Try not floating the img and giving it less margin-left.

Comment: Sadly still the same, no change at all

Comment: Interesting, could you mock up a fiddle? I would post it on your question.

Comment: @Whiz I guess the image is VERY BIG. Isn't it? That's why it's desplayed at the center of the page (including the `margin`).

Comment: @HashemQolami Yes, this was actually the case, I just figured it out seconds ago. I accidently saved the image with a lot of transparent space! I successfully placed image on the left side of the page, but I still have problem making the text look like on the mockup.

Comment: @Whiz Remove `float: right; margin-right: 100px;` from the `<h1>` and use a `margin-top` property to push down the header. Also beware of margin collapsing. if `margin-top` didn't work, use `padding-top` instead.

Comment: @HashemQolami thanks for suggesting the size of the image. I never would have thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

Would u mind using tables, like this?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img align="left" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Nihongo_Bunpou.100x400.png" alt="slider" id="appImg" /></td>
    <td style="padding-left: 50px;"><h1 id="appTitle">Beautiful Voice Recorder<br /><p id="appDescription">The simplest and best looking voice<br /> recorder you'll find on Google Play.</p></h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example of an image and text similar to yours

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQee5/

Tables are also good to position more elements in different alignents in your page. This is one solution if it will work for you.

---

### Solution #2

Althoguh you can use tables, BUT are **not prefferd** as **HTML layouts**, i've put another solution up for You, using proper **DIV** elements and **CSS**.

```
<div id="column-content">
    <img src="http://shrani.si/f/q/1A/4T8mfuFC/nihongobunpou100x400.png" alt="slider" id="appImg" />
    <span><h1 id="appTitle">Beautiful Voice Recorder<br /><p id="appDescription">The simplest and best looking voice<br /> recorder you'll find on Google Play.</p></h1></span>
</div>
```

See the whole code and CSS here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZQee5/2/

Comment: Recommending the use of tables for layout is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Using <table> to create a nice layout is NOT the correct use of the element. The purpose of the <table> element is to display tabular data! - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

Comment: I have published another solution using DIV elements and the proper way you propose.